# android change volume and update icon

Tags: android, volume

I  need to change the volume programatically. So i use :

```
audiomanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

It works but if the volume was previously set to 0, the mute icon in the status bar and within volume popup isn't modify.

How can I update the mute icon when I change volume ?

Answer (score 1):

The mute icon is used for [setRingerMode(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode%28int%29) with [RINGER_MODE_SILENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_SILENT).